# IMAP Dovecot cannot connect

Tags: ssl, postfix, smtp, dovecot, imap

I am trying to set up my own mail server (for 'fun'). I followed [this tutorial](https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql) to the bone. But I get this error message:

```
imap-login: Disconnected (auth failed, 2 attempts in 9 secs): user=<dayuloli@mydomain.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=203.210.7.43, lip=1.2.3.4, TLS: Disconnected, session=<VDW4ua8NzADL0gcr>
```

I am using the SSL certificate and key I have for my nginx web server, on the same machine.

I disabled plaintext authentication by adding these two lines (as per tutorial) to `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-auth.conf`:

```
disable_plaintext_auth = yes
auth_mechanisms = plain login
```

But the `method` in the log entry still says `PLAIN`, and `TLS` is `Disconnected`. Could that be an issue?

There're too many configurations to post them all here. if you think you need more information, please tell me which parts and I will update my question.

Comment: **auth failed** => your IMAP client provided pair of username and password that doesn't match with your username and password stored in mysql

Comment: @masegaloeh I double-, triple-checked my password and username and they are correct. There are so many places where it can go wrong - wrong encryption, missed parameters...I think I will just start again >_<

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your mail client forces using TLS.

To debug you could also try to comment the disable_plaintext_auth option out. Always reload/restart postfix or dovecot when changing something.

Comment: How do I 'force' the client to use TLS? I am trying to connect to it using my phone, and I tried both `SSL` and `TLS` and it didn't work. I will try doing it again from scratch and checking after each step...even though that will taken me much longer!

Comment: Which client do you use? Mostly there is an connection option where you can choose SSL/TLS.

Comment: I just use the one provided by my native Android phone. It let's me select something like 'SSL', 'SSL (Accept all certificates), 'TLS', 'TLS (Accept all certificates)'. And I tried them all already...Now I have reverted back to my old externally hosted mail server...since I was being a cowboy and losing email. I have decided now to host the mail server on its own machine and use a 'dummy' domain to test and make sure everything works